# Indent statement after case only without braces in vim cindent

Tags: vim, case, indentation, braces

My cinoptions is the folowing :

```
:set cinoptions={1s,t0,f0s,g0,i0,(0,=0
```

it works well with brace contained case statement, but not unbraced one :

```
switch(foo)
  {
  case(0):
    {
    ...
    break;
    }
   case(1):
   ... <-- should be indented
   break;
  }
```

i need the {1s for all my code need to be formated like that, if i drop the =0 i get this.

```
switch(foo)
  {
  case(0):
      {
      ...     <-- should not be idented so much
      break;
      }
   case(1):
     ... 
   break;
  }
```

Is there any way to specify vim not to indent case in any special way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly done it myself, using a in house indent method :

```
function Indent(line)
    " Store current pos
    let l:indent = cindent(a:line)
    let l:lineprec = a:line - 1
    let l:linefirst = split(getline(a:line), " ")[0]
    if l:linefirst ==# "{"
      let l:case = split(getline(l:lineprec), " ")[0]
      if l:case ==# "case"
        let l:indent = indent(l:lineprec) + &shiftwidth
      endif
    endif
    return l:indent
endfunction
```

add in .vimrc :

```
:set indentexpr=Indent(line(\".\"))
```

it's kinda specific to my coding style ( case must be followed by a space )